# MSChart enable zoom on graphic when started

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, visual-studio

I have graphics that appear on 365 or more values.
The graphics are very concise.

I want to start up the graphics for it to be zoomable three times.

I can give is zooming with the mouse, but I want it when you start to be increased three times?

Pictures before zoom and after zoom with the mouse.

[image: image1]
[image: image2]

Comment: Have you resolved your problems?

Comment: Yes but I want to fill one datagridView and I dont know how to fill with sql query.. I want to have 4 fixed columns and the next columns I want to auto generate with the values but I dont know how :)) Can you help me ?

Comment: This is another question altogether and as far as I can see it has nothing to do with this one. - If you are happy with the answer, please consider consider [accepting](http://stackoverflow.com/help/accepted-answer) it..! - I see that you have never done this: Go the the (invisible) checkmark at the top left, below the votes of the answer and click it! It turns green and gains us both a little reputation..

Answer (score 0):

To **set the zoom in code** you can use these properties:

```
// get a short reference to the x-axis
Axis ax = chart1.ChartAreas[0].AxisX;
// set the size of the zoomed view
ax.ScaleView.Size = 60;
// set the position of the view
ax.ScaleView.Position = 31;
```

[image]
[image]

Note that 'zoomable three times' or  'increased three times' are not clear requirements. You need to calculate how many points or which range of values you want to display!

Comment: Thanks, works great.
But when I run the program Graphics stand empty.
Once he pressed the scroll button then show the results.
Got an idea how can I fix this?

Link here => 
https://ibb.co/cG2awF

Comment: No, I don't know how/when you fill the chart with data. Right after that you should set the ScaleView properties. If it doesn't show right away, maybe a chart.Refresh helps. Is the Chart hidden in a TabPage? Many details we don't see may be the reason..